# trying to use cl-lexer on a file containing "{" and "}"

Tags: common-lisp, lexer, character-class

Using the file "test-lexer.lisp", I have very slightly modified *lex* to be

```
(defparameter *lex* (test-lexer "{ 1.0 12 fred 10.23e12"))
```

and increased the number of times test repeats to 6

```
(defun test ()
  (loop repeat 6
 collect (multiple-value-list (funcall *lex*))))
```

and tried modifying test-lexer in a number of ways to try to get it to recognize "{" as a token.

For example,  adding [:punct:] in (deflexer test-lexer ...)

by changing

```
("[:alpha:][:alnum:]*"
  (return (values 'name %0)))
```

to

```
("[:alpha:][:alnum:][:punct:]*"
   (return (values 'name %0)))
```

and consistently get errors like

"""Lexer unable to recognize a token in "{ 1.0 12 fred 10.23e12", position 0 ("{ 1.0 12 fred 10.23e")
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]"""

How can i specify "{" as a character to be recognized?  Or is my problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The *cl-lexer* system is based on regular expressions, so you can put any literal character to stand for itself, like `{`. But it happens that the brace character has a special meaning in the regular expression language, so you need to quote it with a backslash. In order to write a backslash in Lisp strings, backslashes need to be escaped. Hence:

```
(deflexer test-lexer
  ("\\{"  (return (values :grouping :open-brace)))  ;; <-- Here
  ("[0-9]+([.][0-9]+([Ee][0-9]+)?)"
   (return (values 'flt (num %0))))
  ("[0-9]+"
   (return (values 'int (int %0))))
  ("[:alpha:][:alnum:]*"
   (return (values 'name %0)))
  ("[:space:]+"))
```

I return the `:open-brace` value and the `:grouping` category, but you can choose to return something else if you want.
The test function then returns:

```
((:GROUPING :OPEN-BRACE) (FLT 1.0) (INT 12)
 (NAME "fred") (FLT 1.023e13) (NIL NIL))
```